# Is there a way to produce a sum according to date/time stamp values of another column on excel?

Tags: excel, sum

I have a csv file of raingauge data, with the following example format:

```
No.    Date/time.           Rainfall
1.     01/21/22 03:13:56    0
2.     01/21/22 03:14:56    0
3.     01/21/22 03:15:56    2.1
4.     01/21/22 03:16:56    1.4
...
```

Is there a way for me to resample this data to produce a daily sum? A formula perhaps?

Comment: Use a pivot table

Comment: a cell to choose a date and a test to put 1 or 0, then sumif() that cell is a 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go with a formula instead of a Pivot Table, assuming the input data for the second column is in date format, you can use the following:

```
=LET(B, INT(B2:B7), C, C2:C7, ux, UNIQUE(B), 
 m, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(x, SUM((B=x) * C))), VSTACK({"Days","Total"}, HSTACK(ux, m)))
```

Here is the output.
[image: output]

**Note**: We use `INT` function to get the date portion of the date&time data.

Using a Pivot table, sometimes Excel is smart enough (but not always) to identify the proper field type, so you can select the day portion of the date and get a similar output:
[image: pivot]

For non O365 version, you can similarly get the result, on cell `E2` put the following:

```
 =UNIQUE(INT($B$2:$B$7))
```

On cell `F2` put the following formula and drag it down:

```
=SUM((INT($B$2:$B$7)=$E2) * ($C$2:$C$7))
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks - works perfectly for me. I am using this formula to teach a workshop - unfortunately they do not have Office 365, instead they have Excel from MS Office Professional Plus 2019. I've tried some troubleshooting and I've discovered that this version of excel does not have the MAP function. Can you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: Thanks, @SHV_la I am glad it worked, for the older versions you can use the Pivot table approach or just follow the step I indicated in my answer. I updated my answer to cover this scenario.